# asp.net 4.5 sessions lost and back after seconds

Tags: asp.net, session-state, iis-8

I have a very strange problem with ASP.NET 4.5 Sessions on Windows 2012

Description:
Sessions work fine. I go through the site, login, access eg profile and other aspx pages which  use the session. then from one second to another, on any aspx page, the session get lost, on every aspx page. after some seconds, the session is back. So if i am logged in before the problem appeared, i lost the session values, and after some seconds they are back.
This happens with every Browser (IE, FF, Chrome).
I did yet tryd to user InProc, State Server, Appfabric, but with all the same, so must have to do something with the .net Session Handling on "toplevel" or with the IIS, whatever...
not sure about, but mostly, subjectivly i think the requests are very slow right before the session get "lost". Crazy, that they "come back" after... so they are not really lost.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

I added some debuging code. have a look at the login, where its most easy to reproduce. here the codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Write("StepA/")
End Sub



Protected Sub btnSignin(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Response.Write("Step0/")
    If System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(loginEmail.Value, loginPassword.Value) = True Then

        Response.Write("Step1/")

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginEmail.Value, False)
        Response.Write("Step2/")

        Dim ui As New UserInfo
        Response.Write("Step3/")
        ui.InitUserInfo(loginEmail.Value)
        Response.Write("Step4/")

        If Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString.Contains("Login.aspx") = True Then
            Response.Write("Step5/")
            Response.Redirect("/admin/Default.aspx")
        Else
            Response.Write("Step6/")
            Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString)

        End If


    Else
        Response.Write("Step7/")
        loginfailed.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

so... Running all normal, inital load, print out "stepA".
Then after login Step0 to 5 or 6

then, for any reason, the session is "lost", the code above dont print out Step 0 to 6. looks like the click event dont fire.
Well... but then, restarting the AppFabric Cache, oh wonder... it works
As I wrote before... Same happens with State Server, then restarting the StateServer resolves the problem and Inproc, restarting IIS or the app resolve it....

Just to be clear. this session lost or whatever problem apears on all aspx pages, not just the login. everywhere where the session is used at least

Comment: Do you have any html META tags? Some meta tags could mess with your Session. More info on sessions on ASP.NET can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: yes, i have
<meta name="description" content="Guia de ..." /><meta name="author" content="exponity Guarulhos | exponity.com" /><meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /><meta name="Googlebot" content="all" /><meta name="Copyright" content="(c) 2012 - 2013 LoLoLo e exponity.com Guarulhos" /><meta name="keywords" content="Guia de Guarulhos, endereço,telefone,mapa,locais,guarulhos,sp" /><meta name="service" content="Locais, Guia de Ruas, Mapa, Localização, Empresas" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: None of those tags would mess up your session.

Comment: i think so too, but what do it then ?

Comment: You could perhaps benefit from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722718/formsauthentication-redirectfromloginpage-keeps-looping however the user has not posted as an answer, he only posted a comment. Look into his comments; hope they can help. Also, I don't know if you've look into other questions in Stack Overflow. Sometimes there are 3 or 4 people who have ask the same question and got the answers. I really can't help no more here, my only guess were the META tags but yours are fine.

Comment: Many tks for the link. Did not found that one yet. Will give it a try and tell you after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of reading, new relic monitoring etc i found the real problem and a working solution.
the problem is related to the fact, that asp.net, until 4.5 block sessions in some scenarios (eg if you have iframes, updatepanel etc), until a page is fully loaded. if a user goes on another page on my side,and the session is blocked, it comes to the described results, waiting time for x seconds etc.

The solution, which works for me, x times better performance but resolved blocking problem:

I use Couchbase (www.couchbase.com) as cash and session "store", with this excellent session and cache provider for couchbase:
https://github.com/evereq/couchbase-aspnet

Important here, related to the blocking probem is the config part: exclusiveAccess="false" for the session provider

2 problems i had, related to Win 8 Dev PC and Win 2012 server.
On Win 2012 we need to replace a dll, described here:

For anyone interested this is a x64 version of a 'wrapper' for libtcmalloc. 
Just place it in your couchbase 'bin' directory and restart the couchbase service.

x64 version of the dll
http://www.mediafire.com/?xc8nurnxjqr8klb

PS: Thanks to Chris Wundram for the hint!

On Win 8 this blog post describes well what to do:

http://blogs.southworks.net/mkrikorian/2013/02/06/installing-couchbase-under-windows-8/

as i said, after this, blocking problems gone and much better performance